# Getting Site Share notification to external user but not using designer WF/Rest-api

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-rest-api

In SharePoint on-premises (SP 2013) I'm using Rest-API to send an email notification to the external user on a button click but I'm getting this error

> **"The e-mail message cannot be sent. Make sure the e-mail has a valid recipient."**

for cross checking purpose I tried with SP Designer list workflow but no success in it as well,***but if I share any site to any external user im getting a notification for same that means the server is configured to send an email notification to the external users***

please let me know if anyone has some solution to it

Answer (score 0):

This issue seems to be about the external users' email, not SharePoint side issue.

Make sure the external users have valid email addresses.

In addition, you said that you could share any site to any external user, make sure you are using same external users when testing in workflow/REST API and sharing a site.

Comment: yes i have checked it multiple times but same user is getting site share Mail but not getting any mail from either REST or through designer List Workflow